# Remapping option / command keys when accessing windows from a mac over PCOIP

Tags: windows, macos, pcoip

I access a windows machine via Teradici client running on a mac.

It is annoying that the mac keyboard causes win and alt keys on the host to be swapped. I can switch those on my keyboard, but then it is annoying to use mac OS (I regularly switch between the 2 os's all day).

It would be less ideal to rely on my keyboard's built in remap function however as I sometimes use the laptop keyboard over PCoIP.

Is there a way to have the PCoIP software remap the key requests in real time, or some other solution?

I have admin access on the local mac, but not on the remote PC.